# How to detect the last Docpad render pass?

Tags: docpad

Im currently writing a small Docpad plugin to output a documents contentRenderedWithoutLayouts into a separate .json file next to the .html version for loading it via an ajax request later.

The plugin works by overriding Baseplugin's render: (opts) -> method and doing a few checks whether we're rendering a document and to html.

I now noticed that this method gets called multiple times for some documents, which seems to be render pass related. So how can I detect the final render pass per document to avoid writing the .json multiple times per render?

Many Thanks

--

Edit:
found the answer after another look at Docpads events list: http://docpad.org/docs/events

The `writeAfter` event is the right place to get the final data and have the output directory tree set up so I can put my .json files next to the .html.

In case you're interested find the plugin here: https://github.com/field/docpad-plugin-jsonfragment

Comment: Sweet! Glad you got it sorted. Can you post your answer as an answer rather than part of your question? That way people will clearly know it's solved. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this would be to use the `serverExtend` event, and write a router that detects if it is an ajax request (existance of the `IS_XHR` header) and then sends the necessary json data from that. This would require your hosting platform to support node.js as you'll be using the docpad server.